# Error while loading shared libraries: libgthread-2.0.so.0

Tags: software-installation

I was trying to try run IDA debugger on my Ubuntu 13.10[64 bit] and many "Error while loading shared libraries" showed up. I installed 32 bit libraries and resolved them but i'm stuck with the libgthread-2.0.so.0. I tried to download and install the .deb package from [here](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/amd64/libglib2.0-0/download), but upon installation software center says already a new version is installed

Any ideas how to resolved this.?

**[Edit 1] Solution**

The problem was the IDA is looking for 32 bit libraries and what I had on my system was 64 bit libraries and what I downloaded was also 64 bit, that is why Software Center said it already exist. 
So solution is to install 32 bit variant of the library

Step 1: Find the package that includes this library

```
#dpkg -S libgthread-2.0.so.0 
 libglib2.0-0:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0
```

Step 2: Install 32 bit version of the same so add i386 instead of amd 64.

```
#apt-get install libglib2.0-0:i386
```

Now everything works fine..

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure this warrants a separate question so I'm posting it here. In order to install IDA Pro on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, it requires a few more 32-bit dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1:i386 libXrender1:i386 libsm6:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386
```

Once you install those, IDA appears to start fine.

Comment: Just one more: libxext6:i386

Comment: If you have some QT xcb error, install `libqt5gui5:i386`.

Comment: This answer helps to install ZTE MF710 Modem Driver on 64-bit Ubuntu 15.10. The way shared knowledge works, amazing!!